# Convert string to sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, string

**convert this string:**

animal,,lion|building,,large|animal,,giraffe|animal,,elephant|building,,small|weight,,120kg|building,,middle

**to sorted array like this:**

```
[animal] => [0] => lion
            [1] => giraffe
            [2] => elephant

[building] => [0] => large
              [1] => small
              [2] => middle

[weight] => [0] => 120kg
```

my solution:

```
$string = "animal,,lion|building,,large|animal,,giraffe|animal,,elephant|building,,small|weight,,120kg|building,,middle";
$array = explode('|', $string);

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $array[$k] = explode(',,', $v);
}
```

but this only gives a nonsorted array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => animal
            [1] => lion
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => building
            [1] => large
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => animal
            [1] => giraffe
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => animal
            [1] => elephant
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => building
            [1] => small
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => weight
            [1] => 120kg
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => building
            [1] => middle
        )

)
```

Comment: You don't have any sorting.  Think about creating another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "animal,,lion|building,,large|animal,,giraffe|animal,,elephant|building,,small|weight,,120kg|building,,middle";
$array = explode('|', $string);
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    list($type,$val) = explode(',,', $v);
    $newArray[$type][] = $val;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Result:

```
array(3) { 
  ["animal"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(4) "lion" 
    [1]=> string(7) "giraffe" 
    [2]=> string(8) "elephant" 
  } 
  ["building"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(5) "large" 
    [1]=> string(5) "small" 
    [2]=> string(6) "middle" 
  } ["weight"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(5) "120kg" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: That's a great comment, but downvoting answers simply because you don't like the question, or why the question is being asked, isn't the solution.

Comment: Your answer isn't sorting, it works because the first level indices are already in order.